# Make a light only affect one object

Tags: unity, lighting

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a light source only affect one object? I know that it's possible to use layers and culling mask, but then I would need one layer for every single object which is not possible.

Is there a way for example that I could make only children or siblings be affected by a light source? Or other solution?

Have a nice day!

**Update #1:**

[image: Example of lighting]

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/8647/view.html):

> Yes, this is what [Layers](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/Layers.html) are for.
>
> Assign your objects to a specific layer (use an existing layer, or
>   create your own custom layer). Then go to the light's inspector pane
>   and adjust the "Culling Mask" setting to have it light (or not light)
>   your desired layers.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that instead of using lighting (as it is very expensive) you can play around with the emission property of the objects material. You can just put the texture you have used in it if you dont want any fancy light emission from it !!

Comment: This might be a viable workaround in some situations, but not in the general case. I actually had this problem before: I had [a "beehive base" like in XCOM](http://media1.gameinformer.com/images/hubs/xcom/xcom_ant_farm_960.jpg) and had a hard time configuring the lights in each room to only affect that room and not the neighbors without having to make them all performance-killing hard-shadow lights (Pre-baking was not an option because the rooms were changing and lights were animated).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I want to achieve is a shiny effect when an object appears. Each time a block is spawned a light is added relative to that block and the light's position is animated thus creating a shiny reflection. I don't think that it's possible with emission since it will affect the entire texture? See updated post for a screenshot.